# Alternatives to wx.lib.masked.NumCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython

In a wxPython application I'm developing I need a lot of input fields for numbers (integers and floats), so I tried using wx.lib.masked.NumCtrl, but my users now tell me that it's quite uncomfortable to use (and I agree with them).

Is there an alternative widget implementation I can use, or should I just roll my own, starting from a bare TextCtrl?

(wxPython 2.8.9.1)

**Edit**
For completeness, here's an example of "uncomfortableness":
given a NumCtrl with `selectOnEntry` and `fractionWidth > 0`, when you switch to the decimal part of the field, it gets correctly selected, but pressing numbers doesn't do anything, you have to delete the contents of the field first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the usual wxPython distribution there's IntCtrl, and then a few other GUI controls like Slider, Spin, FloatSpin, and KnobCtrl.

There's also the [Enthought Traits](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/) approach, and the [GUI part](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/docs/html/TUIUG/index.html) of this seems to have put a fair amount of focus on numerical entry and display, such as [logarithmic sliders](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/docs/html/TUIUG/factories_basic.html#rangeeditor), [float array editors](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/docs/html/TUIUG/factories_basic.html#id3), etc.  Looking at their designs might give some inspiration even if you don't take this path.

Also, it's not really clear why you don't like the masked NumCtrl, but it's very easy to write your own, so if there's some specific thing you want, that's probably the way to go.